# Optimisation select with large IN and millions of records in result

Tags: postgresql, query-performance, optimization, postgresql-performance, performance-tuning

I work with a table which consists of 1.5B records.

DB: RDS, PostgreSQL 12.4, 16GB RAM, 4vCPU

Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE public.trip (
     id bigint NOT NULL,
     cell_to character varying NOT NULL,
     cell_from character varying NOT NULL,
     indicator character varying NOT NULL,
     time_id integer,
     weight double precision
);

CREATE INDEX ix_trip_cell_from ON public.trip USING btree (cell_from);
CREATE INDEX ix_trip_cell_to ON public.trip USING btree (cell_to);
CREATE INDEX ix_trip_indicator ON public.trip USING btree (indicator);
CREATE INDEX ix_trip_time_id ON public.trip USING btree (time_id);
```

I'm trying to pull all trips which happen within some cells (output around 7-12 million records):

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT
    cell_to,
    cell_from,
    time_id,
    weight AS trips
FROM
    trip
WHERE
    cell_to IN (VALUES ... 1k values)
  AND 
    cell_from IN (VALUES ... 1k values (the same as above))
  AND
    time_id IN (VALUES ... 3 to 20 values)
  AND
    indicator = 'some string';
```

The result you can find here https://explain.depesz.com/s/RxH4.

What I've tried:

1. Replaced with INNER JOINs -> got some improvements
2. Changed b-tree index to BRIN -> a bit improved timing
3. VACUUM, REINDEX, work_mem -> zero effect

The query still runs too long.

UPDATE:

Thanks to @NikitaSerbskiy and @Laurenz Albe, forcing postgresql using index and adding a multicolumn index helped a lot.

Comment: Can you give some point of reference of how long it was running before your changes and how long it takes now?

Comment: I started with 15min execution and lower it to 8min.

Comment: have you tried multicolumn index? (indicator, time_id, cell_to, cell_from)

Comment: @NikitaSerbskiy not yet, will try today.

Comment: @NikitaSerbskiy thanks it helped a lot https://explain.depesz.com/s/AEoR

Comment: Didn't you miss to add time_id to the index? Maybe it has a sense to create a temp table with list of time_ids and rewrite query using lateral join for each time_id. Index should start with indicator, time_id, ... or time_id, indicator, ...

Comment: also please try to add weight to the end of the index )

Comment: I've created index like this `CREATE INDEX test2_mm_idx ON public.trip USING btree (cell_from, cell_to, time_id, indicator);`. Will create another one with correct order

Comment:  https://explain.depesz.com/s/wZK0. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might get bitmap index scans and better performance if you increase `work_mem` to something like 200MB or more, so that a bitmap for your table fits into it.

Other than that, the only remedy I can see is using more parallel workers by raising `max_parallel_workers_per_gather`.

But all these optimizations are questionable if you plan to run more than a single concurrent query on this tiny machine.

UPDATE:

Experiments with `enable_seqscan = off` suggest that PostgreSQL overestimates the cost of an index scan.

So if you lower `random_page_cost` to something closer to 1, PostgreSQL should choose the better plan automatically.

Comment: Thanks, actually I forgot to mention I tried to increase `max_parallel_workers_per_gather` to 4 and encountered slight improvement, but still far from a breakthrough. I will try to play with `work_me`.

Comment: Set `track_io_timing` to `on` before you run `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)`, it will tell you how much time is spent doing I/O. Don't expect that query to ever become really fast...

Comment: I found no effect using increased `work_mem` https://explain.depesz.com/s/kD69

Comment: Can you temporarily `SET enable_seqscan = off;` and see if PostgreSQL comes up with an interesting plan (use plain `EXPLAIN` first so you don't have to wait for completion)?

Comment: The plan is definitely different https://explain.depesz.com/s/ya8k. I will check the performance result

Comment: Wow, that looks awesome https://explain.depesz.com/s/3dKD !

Comment: Ah, great. See my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you a lot!

Comment: @Andy - see [what to do when someone answers your question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).  